# Как привлекательно описать вакансию?

Tags: работа

Мы собираемся опубликовать вакансию на хэдхантере. Но мы не уверены в том, что на неё откликнется достаточное количество человек.

Как бы так описать вакансию, чтобы она выглядела более привлекательной для тех людей, которым будет комфортно с нами сотрудничать?

Хорошо бы, чтобы откликнулось много, а мы выберем.

Может, есть какие-нибудь статьи с рекомендациями?

Comment: Напишите правду XD

Comment: Ну да. опишите требования, как это будет на самом деле и что человек, удовлетворяющий требованиям, будет за выполнение оных получать. опишите условия труда - обеды, комнаты отдыха.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишите кратко, но по возможности конкретно (понимаю, что это противоречивые требования) проект. Желательны некоторые технические детали, если угодно "изюминки".

Также претенденту может быть интересен предполагаемый состав участников (количество, квалификация), а также внешние соисполнители и заказчики.

Понятно, что соисполнителей и заказчиков часто нельзя называть, но упомянуть (не конкретизируя) не помешает.

Про оплату и условия труда [@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley) уже хорошо написал.

Answer (score 2):

Самое фиговое что можно сделать - это не указать уровень зарплаты. Если напишете что-то типа:

> Достойная зарплата по результатам собеседования

то вы получите то что и заслуживаете - поток выпускников без опыта и знаний.
Если дело происходит в Москве, то здесь народ избалован и без страховок, условий отдыха, кондиционированных офисов и хороших компов с места попу не подымет.

И кстати, как ни странно, народу нравится когда предлагается на месте работы приличная техника: по 2 монитора, мощные 4-х ядерные процы и проч. ерунда.

Comment: Да, да 2 монитора - это вещь, удобно :)

Comment: а еще ipad)

Comment: > как ни странно ... по 2 монитора

Незаменимо при отладке же, что тут странного?

Comment: дома 24w, не почуствовал необходимости в дополнительном мониторе. а вот на работе 19w - маловато =/

Answer (score 1):

Как я выбирал куда пойти работать:

1. Внушительный список требований.
2. З/П не менее чем в полтора раза выше средней по городу для данного рода деятельности.
3. Обучение, курсы, мониторы, процессоры, плюшки с сахаром.

Вообщем всё то, чего бы хотелось. Для кого-то (наверное для большинства) немалое значение имеет коллектив. Я это не вынес отдельным пунктом, т.к. на работу я не разговаривать и строить глазки хожу, а получать драгоценный опыт и деньги. Всё просто) Хотя коллектив у меня замечательный. Со всеми познакомился на собеседовании. Такие же как я люди)